# What's the most appropriate Metaphor for submitting a selected Item in android App?

Tags: gui-design, android, usability-testing, user-centered-design, material-design

I have designed and implemented an android application for patients aged >30. While conducting a usability Test, I found the following Issues :

1. CheckBox: When the user searches for particular item and decides to choose the one he desires, the checkbox is hard to be activated on small-devices.
2. Most of the participants on the test, tend to have difficulty finding a submitting button which is at the top-right of the tab-menu. What icon should I use or any other method/button? would hover button solve the issue or should I use animation since I am leveraging material design.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **Make the checkboxes bigger** - this is not a problem for users with age 30+ because their vision is not on 100% as before.
2. **Use button**. You should design it to **contrast** your current color scheme so it is easilty visible. Use some accent colors (A100,A200, A400,A700) from the [material design pallete](https://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-color-palette) to do that. You should play with the accent colors to find the best match.

Answer (score 2):

Can you replace the checkbox with a toggle, some kind of select-button?

I would place a large green submit-button at the bottom right of the page. Perhaps in its own row so it will always be visible to the user. The user shall be able to scroll trough the items and when the users is done selecting, the button is there at the "end of the list" were the users most often expect it to be located.

The button might have the text "Select 7 items" if 7 items are selected.